# Service Fabric Transactions are x10 times slower than SQL transactions in another machine

Tags: performance, azure, dictionary, transactions, azure-service-fabric

I have tried transaction in Reliable dictionaries in process and they perform 10x slower than SQL transactions out of  process. We would like to use service fabric but if it can not perform a simple increment task in a transaction in process how can we rely on that.

**On Service Fabric**

Simple Calling GetFromStateful method 5000 times takes around 100 seconds to complete

**On RDBMS**

Same operation takes 10 seconds to complete.( Crazy to be 10x slower even this is out of process)

What I don't get is ?

- Why is that slow ?
- Microsoft promotes this as FAST ?

**CODE**

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Fabric;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections;
   using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
   using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.FabricTransport.Runtime;
   using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;

   namespace Counting
    {
   internal sealed class Counting : StatefulService,
       ICount
   {
       private IReliableDictionary<string, int> _myDictionary = null;

       public Counting(StatefulServiceContext context)
           : base(context)
       {
       }

       protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
       {
           var settings = new FabricTransportRemotingListenerSettings
           {
               MaxConcurrentCalls = 32
           };

           yield return
               new ServiceReplicaListener(
                   context =>
                       new FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener(context, this, settings));
       }

       async Task<int> ICount.GetFromStateful()
       {
           if (_myDictionary == null)
           {
               _myDictionary = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableDictionary<string, int>>("myDictionary").ConfigureAwait(false);
           }

           using (var tx = StateManager.CreateTransaction())
           {
               var result = await _myDictionary.AddOrUpdateAsync(tx, "Counter", 0, (key, value) => ++value).ConfigureAwait(false);

               await tx.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

               return result;
           }
       }
   }
  }
```

Microsoft Service Fabric Team Markets this as

[image]

**From the notes**

Reliable Dictionary periodically removes least recently used values from memory. This is to enable

·        Large Reliable Dictionaries

·         Higher Density: Higher density of Reliable Collections per replica and higher density of replicas per node.
The trade-off is that, this can increase read latencies: disk IO is required to retrieve values that are not cached in-memory.“

**But we can not see any cpu / ram / disc IO when we are doing this action.**

Comment: What's with the `ConfigureAwait(false)` statements?

Comment: removed all and there is no difference. At this line we are slowing down.                await tx.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: does this have an affect \\\\\   [StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
    internal class CountingActor : Actor, ICountingActor

Comment: Pretty sure that's the default value. So no

Comment: From what you post, can't tell what you are doing wrong, but you are doing something wrong as others are able to get 1,000s of requests per second. Maybe you should download the performance sample to see what a correctly written solution can do https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-performance

Comment: As I asked in the other related question as well, post the code of the caller.

Comment: @RıfatErdemSahin did you find the reason eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updating a single record .. SF will put write locks on that .

SF is IMHO designed for 3 cases

- 1) Very small stuff eg Micro services and Actors where the cost of
  managing many SQL servers is cost prohibitive
- 2) Very large scale-   sharding etc..
- 3) High availability , SQL only has fall over and its
  gets pretty hard then.

Remember its a NoSQL so you need to think documents not tables.